# Add Content to WooCommerce Loop without modding functions.php or core files

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, css-selectors

As can be seen in these [examples](https://woofocus.com/add-content-to-woocommerce-product-loop/), I would like to display content at certain positions in the loop.

However, I have to manage the whole thing without modifying core files or the functions.php.

jQuery and its selectors should be able to count the elements and then throw out a new DIV after each line.

I tried something like this:

```
$('.archive ul.products-grid > li:nth-child(4)').after('<div class="stopper" style="width: 100%; height: 185px; border: 1px solid red">Cross-Promotion!</div>');
```

that works fine but how can I get it to show after every fourth element and not only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `nth-child(4n)` to select every 4th element

```js
$('li:nth-child(4n)').after('<li>INSERTED</li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I should have known it was so easy... :) thank you!